# oracle 10g tablespace table relation?

Tags: oracle, sql

Im running "Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production" and trying to get familiar with it. I have created a tablespace und set it online. How do I make sure the next create table statement is using *this* tablespace? Is **store as** dedicated to this? Does oracle automatically figure it out?

Thanks
nn

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options available. The easy one:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (field_a CHAR(1), ... ) TABLESPACE your_tablespace;
```

This will create the table "your_table" in the "your_tablespace" tablespace.

You could also create a user to make him use your tablespace as a default tablespace, thus all his objects (not only tables!) would be created in that tablespace:

```
CREATE USER your_user 
IDENTIFIED BY "your_password" 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE your_tablespace
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;

GRANT CONNECT to your_user;
```

You could also modify an existing user to change the default tablespace:

```
ALTER USER your_user DEFAULT TABLESPACE your_tablespace;
```

From that moment on, all NEW objects will be created in your_tablesapce (Previously existing objects will NOT be moved automatically!)

To move a table from one tablespace to another:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MOVE TABLESPACE your_tablespace;
```

Think that's all...

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick reply, anyone please vote for this guy